# CSS - How to make a side bar w/ increasing margin when you zoom out, decreasing when you zoom in

Tags: html, css, resize

I am making a side bar that will have buttons, etc, with text on the other side. When you initially open the page, the side bar will take up 39% of the left side, which is currently working fine. When you zoom in, the sidebar should shorten (width decrease) and when you zoom out the sidebar should widen (width increase). The problem is when you zoom in from the original position as loaded using the browser, the side bar then goes over to the right too much. Likewise if you zoom out, the side bar goes too much to the left.

In other words, I need the sidebar to retain its original view which is this:
(View how it should always look)

[image: View how it should always look]

When you zoom in or out, it should retain this original proportion. Instead, when you zoom out it does this:
(View when zoomed out)

[image: View when zoomed out]

And when you zoom in it does this:
(View when zoomed in)

[image: View when zoomed in]

So to solve this I need some kind of code that will increase the margin size when you zoom out, and decrease it when you zoom in.

Sorry if this seems dumb. Thank you in advance!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 39%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the sidebar work nice, if you want the font to be equal always, use something like `vw` example: font-size: 3vw; the font always have the same size if zommed, and is also responsive if the width is big it will be big (if zoomed it will be equal always) ... the nly problem with this is: if the width of screen is so small also the font willl be small THE SOLUTION for this maybe is using @media querys, and check if the width of screen is small than this set the font-sizewith a `px` value instead, else it will execute normal css you was write before

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution to my own question:

```html
<html>
    <style>
* { margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box; }
#container {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding:0;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 51%;
    position: relative;
    left: -295px;
    padding:0;
}
#left2 {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    padding:0;
}

</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><div id="left2"></div></div>
</div>
</html>
```